# Can a replacement iPad screen be used on a BeagleBoard?

Tags: display, touchscreen, beagleboard

I have been trying to find a good touchscreen with multitouch support for the BeagleBoard. I have not had much success, but have noticed that iPad replacement screens are available fairly inexpensively. Is it possible to use one of these as the display/touchscreen for a BeagleBoard?

Comment: Of course it's possible, the real question would be if the needed interface data is publicly available or reverse engineer-able, and how complicated an interface adapter or circuit would need to be.  Depending on your other I/O requirements, it might be worth comparing the costs/difficulties of interfacing to some multi-touch tablet and using its on-board processor for the project instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about this touch screen:
http://www.repairsuniverse.com/ipad-2-touch-screen-digitizer-replacement.html

However, without the touch screen controller, it is basically useless. That's because a special controller chip is required to perform the high speed capacitance measurements.

Take a look at this touch screen from 3M (one of the few capacitive touch screens on digi-key, but there are many more out there)
http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/17-8031-205/3M5745-ND/1886090

It requires this controller module:
Digikey part No: 3M9138-ND

I'm willing to bet that controllers are rarely compatible with other touch pannels becuase of the variety of technologies out there.

Also note that Cypress makes a line of capacitive touch screen controllers, called TrueTouch.